# Simple Login Auth React with Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm not sure what I'm missing but I have a simple login page that verifies a user.

This is my `LoginPage.js` function that handles the login.

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { loginUser } from "../actions/auth";

 ...

 << Class declarations >>
 ...

  handleLogin = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const creds = {
      username: e.target.username.value,
      password: e.target.password.value
    };
    console.log("Login data sent ", creds);
    loginUser(creds);
  };

 ...
    << Login Component rendered and form to handleLogin >>
 ...

export default connect(
  undefined,
  { loginUser }
)(Login);
```

Which is sent to `/actions/auth.js`

```
export const loginUser = creds => {
  console.log("login user creds ", creds);
  return dispatch => {
    console.log("inside dispatch ", creds);
    try {
      let response = API.post("api/login", {
        username: "eve.holt@reqres.in",
        password: "cityslicka"
      });

      console.log("Returned Data ", response);
      dispatch(receiveLogin(creds));
      return response;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Axios request failed ", e);
      return false;
    }
  };
};
```

I have put console logs in to see where it goes but I only get:

> Login data **sent**  {username: "test", password: "test"}
>
> login user **creds**  {username: "test", password: "test"}

It doesn't seem to go any further than that so I don't see anything inside the dispatch.

**Edit:** I added that I am actually already using `connect` in the `LoginPage.js`

Comment: `loginUser(creds);` returns a function, and you aren't calling that function. You would need something like `loginUser(creds)(dispatch);` I guess? Not a redux expert.

Comment: are you using redux-thunk or some other redux middleware?

Comment: @ChristopherNgo yes I'm using redux-thunk - still quite new to all this so not sure how to use it exactly

Comment: @Justin see my solution below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of updates we need to make in order for your login feature to work.

You're probably already somewhat familiar with the `React-Redux` flow.

1. A user interacts with your component, they trigger an event
   **(submitting a form/login)**.
2. We handle the event by calling our `dispatcher` function (the function we imported and plugged in connect()),  taking the
   user inputs to formulate a request to the back-end API. **(redux-thunk action-creator)**
3. We wait for the back-end API to verify the user credentials, if
   successful they will give us back a token or user payload. **(Promise-handler)**
4. Use the returned object to dispatch an action, some info for our reducer to
   handle. **(Actual dispatch of action)**

So let's try to create something to resemble that flow. To start, it looks like you've partially set-up an event-handler. The problem is that the `loginUser()` action-creator does not implicitly have access to the `dispatch` method. You need to call it from your props:

```
  handleLogin = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const creds = {
      username: e.target.username.value,
      password: e.target.password.value
    };
    console.log("Login data sent ", creds);
    this.props.loginUser(creds);
  };
```

`this.props.loginUser` has `dispatch` binded to it thanks to the `connect()`, where as directly calling it from the import will not yield any redux functionality. This should be enough to complete 1 and 2.

Next we need to resolve number 3. At this point you should be able to execute the logic inside the `dispatch` function. However, the logic is not synchronous (ie, the flow of execution is not controlled), it does not wait for your API to give us something back before continuing.

You can introduce `async/await` for Promise-handling. In a nut-shell, it means to wait for something to complete before moving forward. Note that this will only work for promises. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

```
export const loginUser = creds => {
  console.log("login user creds ", creds);
  return async (dispatch) => {
    console.log("inside dispatch ", creds);
    try {
      let response = await API.post("api/login", {
        username: "eve.holt@reqres.in",
        password: "cityslicka"
      });

      console.log("Returned Data ", response);
      dispatch(receiveLogin(creds));
      return response;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Axios request failed ", e);
      return false;
    }
  };
};
```

For number 4, I will have to let you decide how to pass that data to your reducer :)

Comment: Amazing! That has really helped clear up some of the confusing with connecting the different parts from Page => Action... now to work on the reducer :)

Comment: @Justin awesome! I'm glad that was helpful to you, writing it out gave me a better understanding as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Your logic has a problem, I guess you want post request, if you get the correct response then dispatch. There is a function returned in your function. It doesn't make any sense to do this. Just execute it.

and use the dispatch function as a parameter is ok.